# Evitar que valores de algumas colunas sejam repetidos, MySql

Tags: mysql

Possuo a seguinte query MySql, os resultados são mostrados como na imagem abaixo, gostaria que não fosse repetido os valores das colunas `Aluno` e `NotaGeral` tendo como base a coluna `Usuario` que é um valor único. não basta pedir para não repetir os valores `Alunos` ou `NotaGeral` pois pode haver notas iguais de usuários diferentes e nomes de alunos iguais, mas sendo usuários diferentes. Alguma sugestão?

```
select avg(IFNULL(fraction, 0))*10 as Media, gg.finalgrade as NotaGeral, u.firstname as Aluno, u.username as Usuario, u.lastname as siem, qas.userid, u.department as Turma, u.institution as Escola, qc.name as cat

FROM mdl_question_attempt_steps qas

inner join mdl_user u on u.id=qas.userid
INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.id=qas.questionattemptid
INNER JOIN mdl_question q On q.id=qa.questionid
inner join mdl_grade_grades gg on gg.userid=u.id
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items gi ON gi.`id` = gg.`itemid`
INNER JOIN mdl_quiz_slots qs ON qs.questionid=qa.questionid
Inner Join mdl_quiz quiz ON quiz.id=qs.quizid
inner join mdl_question_categories qc ON qc.id=q.category

where substring(u.department,2,1) = 4
 AND itemtype = "mod"
 AND itemmodule = "quiz"
 AND finalgrade != "NULL"
 and substr(quiz.name,-1)=1
 and substr(quiz.ano,1,4)=2018
 and u.lastname=213
 and qas.state!="todo"
 and qas.state!="complete"

group by turma, q.category, u.id
ORDER BY turma ASC, `Aluno` ASC, cat DESC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom dia mano, os nomes estão repetindo porque a coluna "Cat" possui mais de um valor para o mesmo "Usuario". O que realmente você quer?

Comment: @WellingtonAraujo,  
Bom dia! então, é por questão de estética mesmo, pois fica estranho repetindo os valores desnecessariamente, por exemplo, no caso da coluna `Cat` tudo bem, devem ser mostrados, pois são valores diferentes, mas no caso das colunas, `Alunos` e `NotaGeral` não fica legal repetir valores iguais para o mesmo usuário, entende?
Obrigado por perguntar

Comment: mas em um select isso é normal... mas caso você queira mostrar isso em um sistema então você terá que usar um FOR ou WHILE

Comment: Entendi, é aí que me perco, rsrs

Comment: existe uma forma de fazer com o "PIVOT Table", nunca fiz ele no MySql só fiz no SQL, no MySql é diferente, se você quiser tentar acesse o link abaixo. Mas mesmo assim prefiro montar ele na aplicação.

https://multitibusiness.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/pivot-table-mysql/

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado @WellingtonAraujo

Comment: Vou postar meu comentário como resposta, ok, ai você pontua por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma forma de fazer com o "PIVOT Table", nunca fiz ele no MySql só fiz no SQL, no MySql é diferente, se você quiser tentar acesse o link abaixo. Mas mesmo assim prefiro montar ele na aplicação usando o FOR ou o WHILE.

https://multitibusiness.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/pivot-table-mysql/